# Counting the number of permutations of a binary multiset that have >=1 partitions all ones?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Given a multiset $S$ of $O$ ones and $Z$ zeros, I'd like to count the number of permutations of $S$ that when partitioned into length $T$ segments have at least one segment that is all ones. ($T$ must of course divide $O+Z$).

For example, given the multiset $\{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$ with 5 ones and 10 zeros, the number of permutations when partitioned into segments of 3 (e.g., one would be $\{\{1,1,1\},\{1,1,0\},\{0,0,0\},\{0,0,0\},\{0,0,0\}\}$) that have at least one $\{1,1,1\}$ is 330.

After messing around with the problem for a while I came to what appeared to work:

$\frac{(t-1)! (o+z) \binom{o}{t} (o-t+z)!}{o! z!}$ for $o,z,t$ ones, zeros, and partition length.

However, I then found that only works for cases where the number of ones is < twice the partition size.

I'm thinking I need to use inclusion-exclusion to extend this to work for all cases, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $N=O+Z$ the number of elements and by $M=N/T$ the number of segments. If you fill $k$ particular segments, you have $\binom{N-kT}Z$ choices left for the zeros. Thus by inclusion-exclusion there are

$$
\sum_{k=1}^M(-1)^{k+1}\binom Mk\binom{N-kT}Z
$$

admissible arrangements.

Comment: Perfect. +1 and accept. I figured PIE was needed, but to be honest while I understand the mechanics of PIE, the how/when/where to apply it eludes me. Could you recommend a text at a high-school level that might provide insight and examples/exercises to develop a better feel for PIE?

Comment: @probablynot: I can't unfortunately, I didn't learn it from a text, but I can recommend the [tag:inclusion-exclusion] here at math.SE; you'll find lots of examples at various levels of difficulty, and they come free with people to ask if you don't understand them :-)

Comment: @probablynot: I went through all my answers that use inclusion-exclusion and added the tag to them. Here's a [search of my answers with that tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6622+[inclusion-exclusion]); feel free to use them and ask questions :-)

Comment: @joriki- I noticed that a few days ago - was searching for examples, noticed that the first couple of pages of results were all you. *Very* much appreciated - I plan to read them *all*.

Comment: @probablynot: You might enjoy [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1738241) :-)

Comment: @probablynot: And [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790058) :-) (A double application of inclusion-exclusion that solves an otherwise rather intractable problem.)