# Counting permutations of binary string where all ones within some distance?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Given a binary string consisting of $O$ ones and $Z$ zeros, I'd like to count the number of permutations of that string where all of the ones are within a window (consecutive positions) of length $L$.

For example, with 5 ones and 6 zeros, there are 81 permutations where the ones are all within $l=7$ consecutive positions (I did this enumerating and counting them).

I *think* that using inclusion-exclusion is the way to solve this, but to be honest I understand the gist of the technique but usually struggle to understand *what* to count and *how* to count them to get the alternating I-E terms.

I tried to adapt an answer from [an earlier question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713969/counting-the-number-of-permutations-of-a-binary-multiset-that-have-1-partition) - it is quite similar, except instead of a straight partitioning of a permutation, it's partitioning with offsets of only 1 per partition, but to no avail.

This seems like it should be quite simple, I'd appreciate some frustration relief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need an inclusion-exclusion argument. Let me use $n_0$ and $n_1$ for the numbers of zeroes and ones, respectively, and let $n=n_0+n_1$. Let $\ell$ be the length of the window; I’ll assume that $n_1\le\ell\le n$.

For $n_1\le k\le\ell$ we can count the number of strings in which the actual window occupied by the ones has length $k$. If the first $1$ is at position $i$, the last is at position $i+k-1$. We must have $i+k-1\le n$, so $1\le i\le n+1-k$, meaning that there are $n+1-k$ possible starting points for the ones. There are $k-2$ positions between the first and last ones, and $n_1-2$ of them must be occupied by ones, so there are $\binom{k-2}{n_1-2}$ ways to place the interior ones. Thus, there are

$$(n+1-k)\binom{k-2}{n_1-k}$$

strings in which the actual window occupied by the ones has length $k$, and there are altogether

$$\sum_{k=n_1}^\ell(n+1-k)\binom{k-2}{n_1-2}$$

acceptable strings.

> With your example of $n_0=6,n_1=5$, and $\ell=7$ this becomes $$7\binom33+6\binom43+5\binom53=7+24+50=81\;.$$

Finally,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n_1}^\ell(n+1-k)\binom{k-2}{n_1-2}&=n\sum_{k=n_1}^\ell\binom{k-2}{n_1-2}-\sum_{k=n_1}^\ell(k-1)\binom{k-2}{n_1-2}\\
&=n\sum_{k=n_1-2}^{\ell-2}\binom{k}{n_1-2}-\sum_{k=n_1-2}^{\ell-2}(k+1)\binom{k}{n_1-2}\\
&=n\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}-(n_1-1)\sum_{k=n_1-2}^{\ell-2}\binom{k+1}{n_1-1}\\
&=n\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}-(n_1-1)\sum_{k=n_1-1}^{\ell-1}\binom{k}{n_1-1}\\
&=n\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}-(n_1-1)\binom{\ell}{n_1}\;.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

> In your example this is $$11\binom64-4\binom75=165-84=81\;.$$

The expression $(1)$ can be manipulated in various ways; for instance,

$$\begin{align*}
n\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}-(n_1-1)\binom{\ell}{n_1}&=n\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}-(n_1-1)\left(\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}+\binom{\ell-1}{n_1}\right)\\
&=(n_0+1)\binom{\ell-1}{n_1-1}-(n_1-1)\binom{\ell-1}{n_1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you! I actually realized (after another hour or so) that I'd overthought it, and I could treat them on a case-by-case basis, ending up with the very sum in your answer's first part. I'm now trying to extend it to answer the same question with the addition of only requiring that $X<=O$ of the ones are within the window. Is that a case that PIE applies? Any hints/pointers appreciated, and thank you again. Accepted and plus.

Comment: @probablynot: You’re welcome. The more general question looks as if it could get messy. I’ve not actually sat down and tried, but it appears that counting the strings that are accepted by a given set of windows, as one would need to do for a PIE argument, could get messy. It might well be worth asking it as a separate question, with a link to this one; that at least gives it a chance of getting more eyes on it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for these kind of counting problems you must build a recursion to handle the valid sequences. And after from the recursion you can build it [generating function](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf).

But this will not be needed for this simple count.

Let $a$ the number of ones, $b$ the number of zeros and $\ell$ the length. From the length and the number of ones you must build "simple distinguishable blocks", in this case by example blocks that start and end with a one, of length less or equal to $\ell$, that contain all the ones.

Then fix an one in the first and last position and count all the possible permutations for the $a-2$ remaining ones in the $r-2$ remaining positions, where $a-2\le r-2\le \ell-2$, i.e. $a\le r\le \ell$ are all the valid length where you can put the $a$ ones inside.

Then for each $r\in\{a,a+1,...,\ell\}$ you will had $\binom{r-2}{a-2}$ different permutations of a string of length $r$ with a one in the first and last position.

And then for each $r$ you have different permutations depending in the number of the remaining zeros in the left or the right of the string, in particular for any $r$ you will had $b-(r-2-a+2)+1=b-r+a+1$ possible permutations.

Then the final answer is

$$\sum_{r=a}^\ell \binom{r-2}{a-2}(b+a+1-r)$$

This formula have a closest form... but Im too lazy to write it now, sorry. You can check it in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Br%3Da%7D%5E%5Cell+%5Cbinom%7Br-2%7D%7Ba-2%7D(b%2Ba%2B1-r)).

P.S.: this seem the same answer that put Brian but with a different wording :P

---

Fighting my laziness I will add a beautiful way to get the closed form of the above sum using [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf):

**Summation by parts:**
$$\sum f\Delta g=fg-\sum {\rm E}g\Delta f$$

where

$$\Delta f(k)=f(k+1)-f(k)\quad\text{and}\quad{\rm E}f(k)=f(k+1)$$

**Finite integral example and notation:**

$$\sum_{k=r}^sf(k)=\sum\nolimits_r^{s+1}f(k)\delta k=\sum\nolimits_r^{s+1}f(k)\delta (k+c)$$

$$\sum\binom{k+a}{k}\delta k=\binom{k+a}{k-1}+C$$

**Our case:**

By summation by parts let $\Delta_r f(r)=\binom{r-2}{a-2}$ and $g(r)=(a+b-r+1)$. Then using the above formulas we get

$$\sum (a+b+1-r)\binom{r-2}{a-2}\delta r=(a+b-r+1)\binom{r-2}{r-a-1}+\sum\binom{r-1}{r-a}\delta r\\=(a+b-r+1)\binom{r-2}{r-a-1}+\binom{r-1}{r-a-1}+C$$

And then taking limits we finally get:

$$\sum_{r=a}^\ell \binom{r-2}{a-2}(b+a+1-r)=\left((a+b-r+1)\binom{r-2}{r-a-1}+\binom{r-1}{r-a-1}+C\right)\Bigg|_a^{\ell+1}=\\\color{red}{\boxed{=(a+b-\ell)\binom{\ell-1}{\ell-a}+\binom{\ell}{\ell-a}}}$$

P.S.: [check it!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+(a%2Bb-l)*+Binomial%5Bl-1,l-a%5D%2BBinomial%5Bl,l-a%5D,+for+a%3D5,+b%3D6+and+l%3D7)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer - the latter part is over my head for now, but I will endeavor to understand it. Thanks also for references, I will download the PDF. Sorry I can't accept two answers - I resorted to checking the first one, but a plus at least - I really appreciate the work.

Comment: @probablynot No problem, my answer is complementary, the essential is on the answer of Brian.